# Как на любом языке читать из бинарного файла блоками по 4K и на ходу кодировать в chunked base64 и отправлять в socket?

Tags: любой-язык

Например, в случае `C` и `POSIX` читаем в цикле блоки из файла вызовом `read`, отправляем их в сокет вызовом `send`. Но как организовать кодирование в `base64` и разбиение на строки заданной длины, если содержимое файла доступно только поблочно, а не целиком?

Comment: используйте буфер размером 4К.

Comment: Кодировки какая?